# Find the number of pages in a Word document Section using Interop

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, office-interop

I'm trying to find the number of pages in a Section of a Word document using Interop in c#.

The main goal is really to find out if a header is visible or not. (E.g. a document is only 1 page, the `DifferentFirstpageHeaderFooter` is enabled, so the `wdHeaderFooterPrimary` exists but is technically not shown (because there's only 1 page and not 2 or more).) So if you can find a different way to figure out how to do this, I'm fine with that too.

Currently, `WdInformation.wdActiveEndPageNumber` works if there is only 1 section in the document, but if there is 2, and I'm doing the processing of the second section, `wdActiveEndPageNumber` gives me the total number of pages including section 1.

```
var section = headerFooter.Parent as Section;
int numOfPages = section.Range.Information[WdInformation.wdActiveEndPageNumber];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have the C# for this, but using VBA syntax what you need for "section n" is

a. if `n = 1` then you look at

```
theDocument.sections[1].Range.Information[WdInformation.wdActiveEndPageNumber]
```

b. if `n > 1` then you establish that section n exists, then look at

```
theDocument.sections[n].Range.Information[WdInformation.wdActiveEndPageNumber]-
theDocument.sections[n-1].Range.Information[WdInformation.wdActiveEndPageNumber]
```

and notice that case (b) can return 0 if you have a continuous section break on the last page of section n. I don't know what that would mean in terms of the headers that you would have, but I'd hope it would mean you just had the first page header.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I came up with as well. I was hoping for something a little cleaner, but I guess this will have to do. The only thing that made it a little more complicated is that I only have the HeaderFooter object (and thus the Section object). So I had to do `var doc = section.Parent as Word.Document; var previousSection = doc.Sections[sectionNumber - 1];`